# By Convention, when creating an application in django is it more common to access the backend directly or use API's to make the CRUD?

Tags: python, django, api

I'm a beginner and now that I've done all the views and html, I'm in a connection phase with the backend, I would like to know what is most used, to do it correctly.
PS: this will have a large number of users

Comment: It depends on your use-case. For example, you have a website, android & iOS app that uses the same backend. In such as case, an API approach will allow you to segregate your frontend from your backend using Django DRF. Another use-case, you have only one website will a small number of users; in other words scaling is not one of your concerns. Then you can go with the regular monolithic approach of Django templates which is using Django to render the website pages.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you expect to do and how you want to operate your application. There is no absolute answer. With an API, your application may be more robust and evolutive but it takes time to implement.

However, if you are learning django, I cannot hurt to learn to make a proper API. Here a nice tutorial https://medium.com/swlh/build-your-first-rest-api-with-django-rest-framework-e394e39a482c